# iOS: how to get messages from mail into my application?

Tags: ios5

is it possible to "copy" mail messages from mail.app on an iOS device into my application? The perfect solution would be an "open with" within mail, but I didn't found anything like that.

Is there any way to get (specific) messages without getting them from the mail server directly?

Thanks a lot,

Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since applications are sandboxed on iOS, there is no way to "copy" emails directly from the Mail application. Applications do not have access to other applications' Documents folder. You would have to develop your own email client, and have that load your email account. This is more of a security feature so other applications cannot, say, sniff your email inbox for pictures and then do something bad with them.